# Vimeo API using Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, vimeo, coldbox

I am trying to utilize a library i found on github

https://github.com/dannyrich/CFVimeoAPIWrapper

Here is my init code

```
        CLIENT_ID = "the id string";
        CLIENT_SECRET = "the secret string";
        ACCESS_TOKEN = "token";
        ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = "token secret";
        PER_PAGE = 10;
        vimeo = createObject("component", "models.vimeoService").init(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
    //error occurs here
        vimeo.setToken(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
    data = vimeo.call( "vimeo.albums.getVideos", 
  { 
    "album_id"="1682859", 
    "full_response"="Y",
    "sort"="date", 
    "page"="1", 
    "per_page"=PER_PAGE 
  }
```

and I am getting the following error

```
Variable VIMEO is undefined.
```

not sure why exactly I am getting this, i mean even with the compnent being created it should define the variable

i know its a stretch, but any help on this at all would be greatly appreciated

Comment: No, because that particular `init()` function is a bit atypical and returns `void`, rather than the component itself. So the captured result becomes null or undefined. Take another look at the example on the GitHub page. It creates an instance, but does *not* capture the result of init().

Comment: youre right, that got me further along for sure, thank you for your help, make it an answer and ill accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `<cffunction name="init" access="public" returntype="void">`

No, because that particular `init()` function is a bit atypical, in that it returns void instead of an object. So the captured result becomes null or undefined.

Take another look at the example on the GitHub page. It creates an instance, but does not *capture* the result of init():

```
<cfset vimeo = createObject("component", "VimeoComponent")>
<cfset vimeo.init(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)>
```